# Specific in-wall cable suddenly gone bad?

Tags: home-networking

EDIT:OK so, I'm a doofus. Essentially, I had mislabeled cables. So when I thought I was testing both ends of the same cable, I wasn't. Now that I've figured this out, the cable in the wall is in fact fine. Whatever was going on, was definitely a networking equipment issue and I think I've traced it to one of the WAPs that appears to have crashed or something. Took it offline for a solid 24+ hours and bringing it back up now, so far everything seems fine. Lesson here is - LABEL YOUR CABLES CORRECTLY!  Thank goodness I didn't start opening walls or something!

Woke up this morning to no LAN.  All hardwired machines, Windows & macOS, were completely offline, but wifi appeared fine.  Rebooted the router (several times during this process) and various computers & switches, no change.

After much trial and error and replacing of cables, switches, and computers, I have definitively narrowed it down to a particular in-wall Cat-6 cable.  We had the whole house wired with Cat-6 in 2009 when we were doing a complete rewire of the house anyway so the walls were open.  Network consists of all consumer-grade equipment, multiple routers acting as WAPs to cover the whole house, plus a couple of passive switches just to allow multiple devices to plug in.

The primary switch that ties all rooms in the house to the cable modem, is in my office.  The cable that runs to the router (WAP) in the kitchen, seems to be the problem child.  If I disconnect it, everything is fine.  If I reconnect it, the entire LAN will die completely (no ability to access anything from any machine, can't ping outside) *anywhere from 1 to 10 minutes later*  I have no idea why there would be this delay.

But the absolutely consistent element, is this one wire to the kitchen.  I have no way to get to it as it's in the walls.  I really need the devices in the kitchen to remain on the LAN, I have no idea what to do here.  Any suggestions on:

A) How could a single in-wall wire suddenly fail, and
B) What to do about this?

Comment: Can the contractor who did the cabling (or other good contractor) use a cable tester to see if there is a cable fault and where; or whether the issue is cable terminations. That would be a good start.

Comment: Original contractor, no. I don't doubt I could hire someone to come check that but I would really rather avoid that. You've pointed out the obvious though - test the cable!!  I have a cable test kit I'd forgotten all about so... I know what my next task is.  Thank you!

Comment: If you plug *only* the "faulty" cable in, does it work?  It seems to me the most likely problem is a cabling loop.

Comment: Welp I think we have our answer.  Dug out the cable tester.  The cable in question passes absolutely no signal whatsoever.  Other cables in the wall pass perfect pin-for-pin signal. So while I can't for the life of me figure out how a cable could mysteriously fail completely... we seem to have the answer. Which is nice to know but... very bad news for me.  =(

Comment: If the ends are punch-down, at least you could try re-punch them [with a proper metal spring-action punch, not a plastic POS;) For all 8 wires to fail, though, really does hint that there's a complete cut through it somewhere. Anybody been doing any DIY lately? Was the cable run through conduit? If so you could try pull a new cable through using the old cable to pull it [if it's not completely cut, of course]

Comment: Nope no DIY whatsoever.  The only sudden thing I can imagine that could result in a totally "cut" cable, would be a rat chewing through it.  We've had rats in the walls before, but that was quite some time ago and we've had someone taking care of that for a few years now. Feels unlikely but, not impossible that one had chewed not-quite-all-the-way-through and the cable finally gave? SHRUG. I'm fairly certain they were not run through conduit unfortunately, I think I recall seeing them stapling cable down while running it. Sigh.

Comment: I did mention tracing cables :D. You might want to post your own answer explaining your process, rather than editing the question

Comment: Yeah... It really was just a process of remembering that my labels didn't quite mean what I thought they meant.  It was done over a decade ago so, I just didn't remember it well until I really thought it through!

Answer (score 1):

> Network consists of all consumer-grade equipment, multiple routers acting as WAPs to cover the whole house, plus a couple of passive switches just to allow multiple devices to plug in.

Well there's a few possibilities and this is how I'd troubleshoot it

- check if the cable run is fine with a pair of PCs on either end with *static* IPs. This rules out cable issues. You could use a cheap cable tester, but most people with networks like yours have PCs lying around, and it lets you check for *functionality* on the cable, not just physical connectivity
- Since there was a power outage check the router itself. Having two DHCP servers could be an issue. Connect a PC with dhcp client enabled to check if the kitchen AP/router is doing DHCP
- trace all the cables and sure there's no loops. I *think* some managed switches/AP have a STP option that would help here. Once again, if it worked before the settings were right but the power outage would do it.

Comment: Good tips thanks!  Only one DHCP in use, the actual modem... it's disabled everywhere else plus the LAN has worked perfectly for many many years.  The two actual switches (as opposed to routers in switch mode) I have are both passive without any settings or configurability of any kind but yeah, worked perfectly fine before plus I swapped them, and the problem persisted. Only commonality is that dang cable, which I will now test.  Appreciate the suggestions!